# Visual Studios won't compile code because of warning C6031 ("Return value ignored: 'scanf')

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings

I am very new and only starting learning how to code a few weeks ago. I downloaded visual studios and tried to use it as an editor and C compiler. I made a program and tried to compile it but it wouldn't due to this C6031 ("Return value ignored: 'scanf') warning. I tried compiling it on a C compiler online and it worked. Not sure how to fix this. Is it a problem with visual studios (v 2019)? This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
    // Define variables
double x, answer;
    // Define the value we will find the sin of
printf("Enter a value for x between (0, 1): ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    // Calculate the sin of value
    answer = sin(x);
    if ((x >= 0) && (x <= 1)) {
            // Display answer
        printf("\nThe sine of %lf is %lf", x, answer); }
    else
{
        printf("Value is not within (0, 1) range.");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: C6031 warns that [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the "*number of receiving arguments successfully assigned*" but the code ignores this return value, and proceeds to use `x` without having checked that it was, in fact, assigned.

Comment: How are you supposed to detect and handle errors with your input if you ignore `scanf()`'s return value? The compiler is trying to help you not shoot yourself in the foot.